# how to include script file in head section when condition is true?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to include jquery into  section, if condition is true. For some reasons script doesnt work for me, not sure what is wrong

```
function loadScript() { 
    var currentLocation = String(window.location); 
    var c = currentLocation.includes('test') 

    if(c===true){  
        //document.write('<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript" src="assets/jquery.js"></scr'+'ipt>');
        console.log(c);
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];  

        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = "jquery.js";
        //head.appendChild(script);
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
        alert("asdsad");
    }
    else{
      console.log('error');
    }
}

loadScript();
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: var c = currentLocation.includes('test')  what you are trying to do here?

Comment: Is there an error in Network tab?
Looks line you are trying to load script from wrong address (from current folder, but in comment it's located in assets)

Comment: That should work as long as it is loaded in the right place (ie if `loadScript` is executed in `<head>` it might not work as `<head>` wouldn't be fully loaded yet). Do you get the console log, the alert, or any error messages? Is the url for the js file correct? Are you at a url with the word `test` in it?

Comment: @PrakashKarena, he is checking, if current url address contains test in it

Comment: @PatrickEvans yes I am, I got in console true. But the script is executed in head section I tried to put it outside it doesnt work.

Comment: @Ivvan I have it in both for testing purposes

Comment: Do you have a live example that reproduces the problem that we can look at?

Answer (score 1):

```
function loadJQueryIfMatch(keyword) {
    if (window.location.href.includes(keyword)) {
        var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
        script_tag.setAttribute('src', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js');
        document.head.appendChild(script_tag);
    }

}

loadJQueryIfMatch("test");
```

Comment: You should explain what was wrong in the original code and how your answer fixes it, not just post code with no commentary.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine `currentLocation.includes('test')` is a case sensitive only.

[load script in codepen](https://codepen.io/ockba/pen/OJJqRaJ?editors=1112)